# Сохраняется ли в современном .Net необходимость делать исключения сериализуемые?

Tags: c#

В .Net Framework были требования делать исключения сериализуемыми с помощью связки из атрибута [Serializable], специального конструктора и метода GetObjectData. И всё для того, чтобы покрыть какой-то кейс, когда исключение будет передаваться в другой AppDomain. К сожалению, я так до конца и не понял, когда это может происходить, и наверное поэтому у меня все ещё вызывает вопрос, нужно ли делать всё это, когда я создаю исключение, которое заведомо будет бросаться только в .Net5+

Comment: [NUnit will create one or more separate AppDomains by default, in order to isolate your code from the NUnit runner itself, and it is reasonable to expect that other unit test frameworks do the same. – 
Antitoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066701/why-should-i-always-make-my-exceptions-serializable-net#comment87789687_1066714)

Comment: Не нужно, Serializable устарел и не используется в современных сериализаторах.

Comment: @Grundy, и в .Net5+ тоже?

Comment: @4per да, ещё до появления .NET Core

Comment: Спасибо всем, конечно, но лучше бы полный нормальный ответ увидеть. А то даже не ясно, кто на что отвечает.

Comment: как теперь работает NUnit ?

Comment: Framework Design Guidelines, 3-е издание (2020) по-прежнему содержит рекомендацию DO make exceptions runtime serializable.

Answer (score 6):

В 2020-м разработчики .Net опубликовали план постепенной отмены `BinaryFormatter`. В частности, они планировали заморозить `[Serializable]` в `.Net 6`, т.е. перестать создавать новые классы с этой аннотацией. [ЗА ОДНИМ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕМ](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md#no-new-serializable-types-introduced-net-6)

> The exclusion is for dotnet org first-party projects which target *netstandard2.0* or earlier. For these projects, Exception-derived types should continue to be annotated as [Serializable] so that they may be remoted across app domain boundaries.

То есть, насколько я понимаю, предполагается использовать `[Serializable]` только для совместимости со старыми окружениями. Если же у вас всё окружение на .Net 6 и выше, то `[Serializable]` не требуется.